# Using jQuery, relative paths within a div are updated to absolute paths but having trouble rewriting it to be more dynamic

Tags: jquery

The following code searches for all href's with a specified URL inside a specific div. Then it adds on the domain to create an absolute path.

```
$('#landing-page').find('a[href^="/catalog.php"]').each(function(element, index){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    href = href.replace('', 'http://www.mydomain.com');
    $(this).attr('href', href);
});
$('#landing-page').find('a[href^="/upgrade"]').each(function(element, index){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    href = href.replace('', 'http://www.mydomain.com');
    $(this).attr('href', href);
});
```

Hover over the links in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/zTahG/) to see it in action.

My next step is to make it more dynamic but I'm struggling. I believe I need to create an array and then have it loop through it. Here is what I started...

```
var foo = {
    '/catalog.php',
    '/upgrade'
};

$('#landing-page').find('a[href^="' + foo + '"]').each(function(element, index){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (foo = href) {
        href = href.replace('', 'http://www.mydomain.com');
        $(this).attr('href', href);
    } 
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/sWfn6/).

I can't seem to get it to work. Other times it adds the domain to all the links and that creates a new problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your second fiddle has a few syntax errors. Clicking the "JSHint" button at the top can be very helpful.

Comment: your `foo` is an object yet you use it like a string.  You should probably create a string array replacement for foo and process that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your `foo` variable should be an array, not an object. Secondly you need to loop through that array and test for each value individually. Try this:

```
var foo = [
    '/catalog.php',
    '/upgrade'];

$.each(foo, function (i, value) {
    $('#landing-page').find('a[href^="' + value + '"]').attr('href', function(i, value) {
        return 'http://www.mydomain.com' + value;
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sWfn6/9/)

This does seem to be a rather odd requirement. Could you not change the source directly? Or even use a `base href` meta tag?

Comment: Thanks Rory! Yes, I could change the source directly. Here, because of policies and application restrictions, we are very limited—no git, Sass, yoeman, write access, etc. We do not have access to the <head> element. This script made a major improvement to our current workflow. The #landing-page div could contain up to a hundred links. During stakeholder review we can add it. When it is sent to production it can easily be removed. It's too easy to make a mistake with find and replace. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = {
    '/catalog.php':'http://www.mydomain.com',
    '/upgrade':'http://www.mydomain2.com'
};
$.each(foo,function (search,prefix) {
    $('#landing-page').find('a[href^="' + search + '"]').each(function(element, index){
        $(this).attr('href',prefix + $(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U9RXL/1/

Comment: Thanks cske! This works great. I'll keep it in mind if we run into a situation where we need multiple domains.